# What is the difference between Foreman and Hue for Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, foreman, hue

In researching various administration platforms I would like to know the difference between, when to/not use Foreman and Hue for Hadoop/HDFS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an apples to oranges comparison, as the two have completely different purposes.

[Hue](http://gethue.com/) is an interface that is used to analyze data that lives within your Hadoop environment, allowing easy access to Hive/Impala interfaces, a logical representation of your HDFS filesystem, and more.  This tool would be used by your analysts and decision makers in order to derive meaning from the data you've been working so hard to collect (or at the very minimum, make pretty graphs with it), and for administrators to manage the logical filesystem, Hive/Impala tables, and Mapreduce Jobs.

[Foreman](http://theforeman.org/) is a tool for managing physical and virtual servers on your cluster, allowing you to manage, configure, provision, and monitor your nodes.  This tool would be used by your administrators to manage the physical aspects of your cluster, such as adding/removing nodes and making sure your nodes are performing (generally, by looking at pretty graphs).

The only thing these tools have in common are their shared capacity for producing pretty graphs.

Comment: Regarding 'pretty graphs': then what about Tableau?

Comment: I have not worked with Tableau myself, but I do know that Tableau's pretty graphs capabilities are unparalleled in terms of producing graphs quickly and with relatively little training necessary, though it requires a hive or impala connection to work with your data.  Data and tools outside of Impala/Hive queries, such as HDFS file browsing and operations, and MapReduce job management, will not be available.  In our environment, we tend to use Hue to administrate tables/hdfs and tableau for the pictures, and analysts here query with both.